# How to call .bash_logout on CentOS

Tags: linux, bash, centos, logout, exit

I'm trying to call my own .bash_logout on CentOS when a user logs out. However, even when an 'exit' command is sent, .bash_logout is NOT called/executed (it just logs out).

On CentOS, when I type 'exit' and click on 'Return', the system displays 'exit', and then nothing happens. On other linux systems, when I type 'exit' and click on 'Return', the system displays 'logout', and then it calls my .bash_logout.

Is there any way to call .bash_logout on exit on CentOS?
(Or, any way to execute a script on exit.)

Any suggestion would be helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: No login? No logout. Your bash is not a login shell.

Comment: @Cyrus: Thanks, actually I know that, but could you tell me what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `~/.bashrc` and start a new bash:

```
trap "source ~/.bash_logout" EXIT
```

---

See: `help trap`